# How can I redirect direct linked affiliate links on my site?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink, affiliate

I know, i should have been setting it up differently, but over the past year ive been creating posts on my blog and direct linking to an affiliate site with my affiliate link.

Now the site isnt converting as great and I want to try and change the destination to another program without having to manually go through each post and change it all.

Im thinking it might be possible in htaccess to tell my server: "redirect all outgoing http://www.affiliatelink.com/blahblahblah?23458 clicks to X location" even if the link isnt pointing to a domain that I own, if you know what im saying.

Ive read into htaccess redirecting and it talks about redirecting sub folders to any URL you wish but it only works for links that are on my domain and not external links like im trying to do.

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

that's not possible using `.htaccess`, you should use one of web programing languages like [php](http://php.net/) to achieve what you want!